Portfolio Optimization Maximizing Sharpe Ratio Allowing Shorts
hope you find all well
I'm currently exploring portfolio optimization techniques aimed at maximizing the Sharpe ratio while allowing for short selling. My constraints are upper bound of 0.5 and a lower bound of -0.5.
Question 1: What shape will my optimization function take given these constraints?
Question 2: Will a local optimum converge to a global optimum in this scenario?
Question 3:Would the residual/difference from the sum of the assets' weights with the maximum allocation (0.5*the number of assets) provide the percentage to allocate in the risk-free rate asset?
